# MS Project. Need a field that flags what tasks have only completed predecessors that I can bring through to MS Project online

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I'm using MS Project which is connected to a PWA. All users complete their tasks on the online 'Tasks' page. For the task owners, I need a flag that tells them that all the predecessors for their task is complete. 
I can see how to do this in VBA with the following code:

```
Sub GetPredStatus()
Dim pj As Project
Dim t As Task 'subject task
Dim p As Task 'Predecessor task
Set pj = ActiveProject

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If t Is Nothing Then GoTo NextTask

    For Each p In t.PredecessorTasks
        If p.PercentComplete < 100 Then
            t.Flag7 = False
            GoTo NextTask
        End If
    Next p
t.Flag7 = True
NextTask:
Next t
End Sub
```

The problem is, I need this flag to be 'live' and accurate to task users in the PWA. 
Is this possible?